# Poor performance on simple query

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I have a query in a function to select the top row and another for the last row, each query takes around 300ms to execute, and this query is executed a lot of times making the function useless

This is the query (this is a test, in the function parameters change):

```
SELECT the_geom
FROM "Entries" 
WHERE taxiid= 366 and timestamp between '2008-02-06 16:00:00' and timestamp '2008-02-06 16:00:00' + interval '5 minutes' 
ORDER BY entryid DESC 
LIMIT 1;;
```

and this is the EXPLAIN ANALYZE output of the query:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                           

---------------------------------------------------------------------     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Seq Scan on "Entries"  (cost=0.00..63538.80 rows=70 width=51) (actual time=184.409..342.049 rows=56 loops=1)
Filter: (("timestamp" >= '2008-02-06 16:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("timestamp" <= '2008-02-06 16:05:00'::timestamp without time zone
) AND (taxiid = 366))
Rows Removed by Filter: 2128847
Planning time: 0.191 ms
Execution time: 342.088 ms
(5 rows)
```

Is there a better way of getting top and last row?

**EDIT:**
Thanks Drunix, that did help but, something that i cant understand is happening, with the index you suges i was able to go from ~300 ms to 0.2 ms

but if i change the time interval that is added to the timestamp to 120 minutes the index is not used and it keeps taking 300 ms

here is the proof(5 minute interval):

```
snowflake=# explain analyze Select the_geom from "Entries" 
where taxiid= 366 and "timestamp" between '2008-02-06 16:00:00' and "timestamp" '2008-02-06 16:00:00' + interval '5 minutes'
ORDER BY entryid ASC 
LIMIT 1;

QUERY PLAN                                                   

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Limit  (cost=149.52..149.52 rows=1 width=55) (actual time=0.129..0.129 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Sort  (cost=149.52..149.70 rows=73 width=55) (actual time=0.127..0.127 rows=1 loops=1)
     Sort Key: entryid
     Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
     ->  Index Scan using entriesindex on "Entries"  (cost=0.43..149.15 rows=73 width=55) (actual time=0.045..0.090 rows=56 loops=1)
           Index Cond: ((taxiid = 366) AND ("timestamp" >= '2008-02-06 16:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("timestamp" <= '2008-02-06 16:
05:00'::timestamp without time zone))
Planning time: 0.266 ms
Execution time: 0.180 ms
(8 rows)
```

the other one(120 minutes interval):

```
snowflake=# explain analyze Select the_geom from "Entries" 
where taxiid= 366 and "timestamp" between '2008-02-06 16:00:00' and "timestamp" '2008-02-06 16:00:00' + interval '120 minutes' 
ORDER BY entryid ASC 
LIMIT 1;

QUERY PLAN                                                        

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Limit  (cost=0.43..60.02 rows=1 width=55) (actual time=245.570..245.570 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Index Scan using "Entries_pkey" on "Entries"  (cost=0.43..97542.75 rows=1637 width=55) (actual time=245.568..245.568 rows=1 loops=1)
     Filter: (("timestamp" >= '2008-02-06 16:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("timestamp" <= '2008-02-06 18:00:00'::timestamp without tim
e zone) AND (taxiid = 366))
     Rows Removed by Filter: 853963
Planning time: 0.277 ms
Execution time: 245.616 ms
```

Comment: Do you have an index on (taxiid, timestamp)? Order is important.

Comment: @Drunix, not according to the execution plan - it scanned "Entries".  It sure would help.

Comment: @Clay the execution plan shows that no Index is used, but there are more possible explanations than the obvious "there is none". Therefore the formulation as (guiding) question.

Comment: Please show definitions of all indexes on the table

Answer (score 1):

Ok, rephrasing my comment as an answer:

Unless you already have it you should create a composite index:

```
create index somename on Entries(taxiid, timestamp);
```

According to your execution plan the combination of these fields should be rather selective, therefore an index scan should be more efficient. Note that an index on `(timestamp, taxiid)` is probably much less useful, because it will only be used to limit the row by timestamp. Put the columns that are checked for equality in front in similar cases.